# Why are there multiple resolution icons in an icon theme?

Tags: icons, themes

Today I was browsing my Ubuntu's file system and found out that there the icon themes folders such as Adwaita, Yaru, have several icons which look the same, with the same name, but having different resolutions inside folders named as **16x16**, **24x24**...
[image]

Why are there multiple icons which look the same?
Isn't that an overkill?
Why isn't there a single set of **vector** icons which can scale to a wide range of resolutions?

Comment: How long do  you use Linux?

Comment: For about 6 months.